# How to rotate a div, while jQuery animates the same div

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, jquery-animate

I have the code...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#box").animate({ 
       top: "250px",
       left: "500px",
       width: '300px',
       height: '250px',
     }, 2000 );

});
```

...to move and change the size of my div.

I was looking around on the internet and found a function that allows a div to rotate using jQuery. Unfortunately jQuery uses CSS to do this which means it doesn't allow the div to rotate while it is changing size and position.

What I'm hoping for is that the div is rotating, increasing in size, and changing position, all at the same time. I'm not sure if this is possible but if it is could you explain to me how it's done.

The only thing I can think of is that I do all 3 animations using CSS instead of jQuery. How is this possible, or what's the easiest way to do what i'm trying to do. Thanks a lot  !!

Here is my CSS code:

```
    #box{

        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
        width:1px;
        height:1px;
        background:#D8D8D8;
        border:2px solid black;
        position: relative;
        margin-left:100px;
        margin-top:150px;


    }
```

Comment: "jQuery uses CSS to do this which means it doesn't allow the div to rotate while it is changing size and position" - I don't see the relevance to be honest, why can't you animate multiple properties at the same time? How did you rotate the element?

Comment: CSS animates the rotation before jQuery animates the change in position and size. So it rotates, then it changes size. Instead of rotating and changing size at the same time.

Comment: Could you make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net where this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's messy, but throwing in some CSS animations did the job.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pd426/1/

The new CSS:

```
#box{

        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
        width:1px;
        height:1px;
        background:#D8D8D8;
        border:2px solid black;
        position: relative;
        margin-left:100px;
        margin-top:150px;


    transform:rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */


    animation: rotate 2s;
-webkit-animation: rotate 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */

    }

@keyframes rotate
{
from {    transform:rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */}
to {    transform:rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {    transform:rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */}
to {    transform:rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */}
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, could you give me a brief explanation on what you did there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure... I didn't touch your jQuery, this is all just CSS animation that supplements your jQuery. The initial rotation, `transform:rotate(0deg)` is set on the div, then it animates using the keyframes below. Look into CSS animations for more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `transform`

```
transform:rotate(7deg);
```

You can rotate according to the degree `rotate(7deg)`